# Firestore automatic backup using new Pub/Sub function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So for a few months now Firestore supports https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/04/schedule-cloud-functions-firebase-cron.html

On the guide to schedule data exports, the recommended way to do it is through App Engine : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export

I was wondering if it was possible to do it directly from a cloud function, scheduled. If so, what would be the way to go? How to use the googleapis, specifically how to configure the scopes, how to call `exportDocuments` REST resource...

Answer (score 2):

I havent built the function yet, but so I far I've managed to do it using this script I wrote with a service account key.

**firestoreBackup.js**

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import serviceAccount from './serviceAccounts/your-service-account-key.js';

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://your-app.firebaseio.com"
});

const client = new admin.firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient({});

async function doFirestoreBackup() {
  try {
    const response = await client.exportDocuments({
      name: client.databasePath('your-project-name','(default)'),
      outputUriPrefix: 'gs://your-project.appspot.com/firestore-backups/2019-08-25-T-12H00/'  // THIS IS YOUR BUCKET. YOU CAN CHOOSE THE FOLDER
    });
    console.log(response);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err.msg);
  }
}

doFirestoreBackup();
```

I'm using `babel-node` to execute it:

```
// TO RUN THE SCRIPT (NAVIGATE TO FOLDER)
C:\...\src\adminScripts\> npx babel-node firestoreBackup.js
```

Comment: Okay, will try that in the coming days and report, thanks :)

Comment: @pepe for me, yes. That exact same code is how I'm doing my backups. I still haven't tested it on how to import it back, but the files are being created and I can see them inside the bucket.

Comment: It works great :) Although, a backup is only usefull if it can be reapplied when needed... Do you know how to do that? `importDocuments` is needed I guess but I'm not sure how

Comment: Yes the files are being created, although it's a little strange format - `all_namespaces/all_kinds` and then a bunch of `output-x` stuff

Comment: Okay, did it, it was pretty simple - called `importDocuments` instead of `exportDocuments`, modified `outputUriPrefix` with `inputUriPrefix` and its value to the folder I wish to import (with the date created earlier as the folder name).

Comment: As for using this with Firebase functions, maybe the solution would be to give the Firebase user the import/export role in `IAM`?

Comment: The file structure is a bit strange. I was hoping to inspect the data in them, but they are in a binary format. Good to know the import is also easy! Thanks.

Comment: I'll be running it from a cloud function called by the cloud scheduler. Since it will be running inside a firebase cloud function using the `firebase-admin` I'm guessing the authorization will be implicit. I'm using the serviceAccount key because so far I'm running it from my local environment as a script. What do you think?

Comment: I'm doing the same as you for now, will take the time to test the function when I have some spare time for it, but it would be logical the authorization should be implicit since Firebase is already using Cloud Storage for its own assets, I see the uploaded images of my app in there... We'll see

Comment: Works from the functions but not from the app engine, any ideas? Same service account..